# Handle very large data in C++

Tags: c++, csv, large-data

I have a `.csv` file which has ~3GB of data. I want to read all that data and process it. The following program reads the data from a file and stores it into a `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`. However, the program runs for too long and the application (vscode) freezes and needs to be restarted. What have I done wrong?

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "sheet.hpp"

extern std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& str, const std::string& delim);

int main() {
    Sheet sheet;
    std::ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("C:/Users/1032359/cpp-projects/Straggler Job Analyzer/src/part-00001-of-00500.csv");
    std::string line;
    while(inputFile >> line) {
        sheet.addRow(split(line, ","));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

// `split` and `Sheet`'s member functions have been tested thoroughly and work fine. `split` has a complexity of N^2 though...

---

EDIT1: The file read has been fixed as per the suggestions in the comments.

The Split function:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& str, const std::string& delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> vec_of_tokens;
    std::string token;
    for (auto character : str) {
        if (std::find(delim.begin(), delim.end(), character) != delim.end()) {
            vec_of_tokens.push_back(token);
            token = "";
            continue;
        }
        token += character;
    }
    vec_of_tokens.push_back(token);
    return vec_of_tokens;
}
```

---

EDIT2:
dummy csv row:
`5612000000,5700000000,4665712499,798,3349189123,0.02698,0.06714,0.07715,0.004219,0.004868,0.06726,7.915e-05,0.0003681,0.27,0.00293,3.285,0.008261,0,0,0.01608`

```
limits:  
field1: starting timestamp (nanosecs)
field2: ending timestamp (nanosecs)
field3: job id (<= 1,000,000)
field4: task id (<= 10,000)
field5: machine id (<= 30,000,000)
field6: CPU time (sorry, no clue)
field7-20: no idea, unused for the current stage, but needed for later stages.
```

---

EDIT3: Required Output

remember the .thenby function in Excel?
the sorting order here is sort first on 5th column (1-based indexing), then on 3rd column and lastly on 4th column; all ascending.

Comment: Beware that `split` is copying its argument each time it is called. You can change the argument type to `const std::string &` to pass them by reference.

Comment: Related : [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons). You need to check that `std::getline` succeeded before using the result. Checking that the stream is still OK before each read is not sufficient.

Comment: It is important to make sure that you are testing your code with optimizations enabled. C++ and its standard library is usually designed with the assumption that optimizations are used. You didn't share how you compile this code, so it is hard to say how to enable optimizations in your case.

Comment: Are all the fields in one row really strings?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, not exactly, they are doubles and integers (or longs?) and strings.

Comment: @justanotherguy Ok, in that case I'd create a `class`  with the appropriate types and overload `operator>>` for that class instead.

Comment: The more you know about a file format, the faster you can process it. CSV is generic. Generic discards a lot of opportunities for efficiency. What Ted is suggesting is if that `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`always follows a particular pattern, you can exploit the pattern.

Comment: @justanotherguy I'm suggesting that you use a class `std::vector<record>` in which `record` contains the proper types, like those you mentioned.

Comment: The `split` method checks every character to see if it's one of potentially multiple delimiters. If you want speed, don't allow more than one delimiter at a time. If your data is more complicated with stuff like quoted strings that may contain the delimiter, you need a smarter parser, but those extra smarts will come at a cost and you want a s few costs as possible.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244431/discussion-on-question-by-justanotherguy-handle-very-large-data-in-c).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start by defining a class to carry the information about one record and add overloads for `operator>>` and `operator<<` to help reading/writing records from/to streams. I'd probably add a helper to deal with the comma delimiter too.

First, the set of headers I've used:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>   // sort
#include <array>       // array
#include <cstdint>     // integer types
#include <filesystem>  // filesystem
#include <fstream>     // ifstream
#include <iostream>    // cout
#include <iterator>    // istream_iterator
#include <tuple>       // tie
#include <vector>      // vector
```

A simple delimiter helper could look like below. It discards (`ignore()`) the delimiter if it's in the stream or sets the `failbit` on the stream if the delimiter is not there.

```cpp
template <char Char> struct delimiter {};

template <char Char> // read a delimiter
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, const delimiter<Char>) {
    if (is.peek() == Char) is.ignore();
    else is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    return is;
}

template <char Char> // write a delimiter
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const delimiter<Char>) {
    return os.put(Char);
}
```

The actual `record` class can, with the information you've supplied, look like this:

```cpp
struct record {
    uint64_t start;       // ns
    uint64_t end;         // ns
    uint32_t job_id;      // [0,1000000]
    uint16_t task_id;     // [0,10000]
    uint32_t machine_id;  // [0,30000000]
    double cpu_time;
    std::array<double, 20 - 6> unknown;
};
```

Reading such a record from a stream can then be done like this, using the `delimiter` class template (instantiated to use a comma and newline as delimiters):

```cpp
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, record& r) {
    delimiter<','> del;
    delimiter<'\n'> nl;

    // first read the named fields
    if (is >> r.start >> del >> r.end >> del >> r.job_id >> del >>
        r.task_id >> del >> r.machine_id >> del >> r.cpu_time)
    {
        // then read the unnamed fields:
        for (auto& unk : r.unknown) is >> del >> unk;
    }
    return is >> nl;
}
```

Writing a record is similarly done by:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const record& r) {
    delimiter<','> del;
    delimiter<'\n'> nl;

    os << 
        r.start << del <<
        r.end << del <<
        r.job_id << del <<
        r.task_id << del <<
        r.machine_id << del <<
        r.cpu_time;
    for(auto&& unk : r.unknown) os << del << unk;
    return os << nl;
}
```

Reading the whole file into memory, sorting it and then printing the result:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::filesystem::path filename = "C:/Users/1032359/cpp-projects/"
                                     "Straggler Job Analyzer/src/part-00001-of-00500.csv";
    
    std::vector<record> records;

    // Reserve space for "3GB" / 158 (the length of a record + some extra bytes)
    // records. Increase the 160 below if your records are actually longer on average:
    records.reserve(std::filesystem::file_size(filename) / 160);

    // open the file
    std::ifstream inputFile(filename);

    // copy everything from the file into `records`
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<record>(inputFile),
              std::istream_iterator<record>{},
              std::back_inserter(records));

    // sort on columns 5-3-4 (ascending)
    auto sorter = [](const record& lhs, const record& rhs) {
        return std::tie(lhs.machine_id, lhs.job_id, lhs.task_id) <
               std::tie(rhs.machine_id, rhs.job_id, rhs.task_id);
    };
    std::sort(records.begin(), records.end(), sorter);

    // display the result
    for(auto& r : records) std::cout << r;
}
```

The above process takes ~2 minutes on my old computer with spinning disks. If this is too slow, I'd measure the time of the long running parts:

- `reserve`
- `copy`
- `sort`

Then, you can probably use that information to try to figure out where you need to improve it. For example, if sorting is a bit slow, it could help to use a `std::vector<double>` instead of a `std::array<double, 20-6>` to store the unnamed fields:

```
struct record {
    record() : unknown(20-6) {} 

    uint64_t start;       // ns
    uint64_t end;         // ns
    uint32_t job_id;      // [0,1000000]
    uint16_t task_id;     // [0,10000]
    uint32_t machine_id;  // [0,30000000]
    double cpu_time;
    std::vector<double> unknown;
};
```

Comment: Your answer is very precise and complete (+1 for the time and effort you put in it), but I have a question "are we sure that give this kind of solutions is the right way to help people?". I mean, now he just needs to copy/paste what you did. You could say "well, that's his problem if he doesn't want to understand things.". But is not our job as engineers (or whatever) to eliminate the possibility to make mistakes where possible?

Comment: @Federico Yes, I agree to some extent. It's however hard to just describe the ideas. I myself got similar snippets as answers when I asked questions (in an older forum a long time ago) from a user there and it helped me immensely to learn from those.

Comment: @Federico, I never just copy/paste stuff. I will not use this answer until I understand how it works thoroughly. If I am not able to understand something, I will pester poor Ted for explanation till I do :D

Comment: Not to mention, this is another account I have, because, well I am not allowed to sign in using my personal accounts on the company workstation. In person, I am kind of a lower-moderate reputation [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11930602/kesarling-he-him)

Comment: @justanotherguy :You're welcome to _"pester"_ me as much as needed :-) If you tell me what parts you spend most time on, I can try to make those parts clearer.

Comment: @justanotherguy I was not saying this could be your specific case. I was trying to understand myself what could be the best way to help people answering this kind of questions. Because we often say on this website "we can't do all the work for you", but it seems sometimes that is the right way to go. I am not very good with explanations and teaching things, so I was just trying to learn something myself. But I am OT. Thanks anyway to Ted too.

Comment: @Federico I find the balancing act a bit hard too. Just dumping a lot of code on the questioner may promote cargo cult programming while including too little may not get the idea through properly. It's tricky, but I pretty much try to answer in a way I like answers myself and I rarely answer questions where the OP haven't show any effort or provided their own code.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, when I answer questions, (and I am not implying that your way is wrong), what I usually do is try to write an answer that me, if I were a noob, would have understood. That includes stuff like helpful links to the library documentation (for example a good tutorial which explains how to use a particularly advanced library function), or link to a tutorial which explains the coding pattern I have used in more detail, etc. In this particular case, we don't need all that, for I have been doing "advanced (??)" stuff like this for quite a while :)

Comment: @justanotherguy Yes, I did assume that both you and others finding this question later on are already familiar with templates and operator overloading etc. to some extent - but it's always possible to improve an answer and I may return to do so later :)

Comment: @TedLyngmo, again, this particular answer does not need improvement. This is really good and I doubt anyone who's that new will ever stumble upon this. Some things are meant only for advanced users, and they are meant to be kept that way for a reason :) I haven't had time to work on this side project since yesterday (too many sprint backlogs) so I haven't gotten around to trying it out yet though.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate way to solve this problem, I would suggest to not read all data in memory, but to use the minimum amount of RAM to sort the huge CSV file: a `std::vector` of line offsets.

The important thing is to understand the concept, not the precise implementation.

As the implementation only needs 8 bytes per line (in 64-bit mode), to sort the 3 GB data file, we only need roughly 150 MB of RAM. The drawback is that the parsing of numbers need to be done several times for the same line, roughly `log2(17e6)`= 24 times. However, I think that this overhead is partially compensated by the less memory used and no need to parse all numbers of the row.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <fstream>

std::array<uint64_t, 5> readFirst5Numbers(const char* line)
{
    std::array<uint64_t, 5> nbr;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        nbr[i] = atoll(line);
        line = strchr(line, ',') + 1;
    }
    return nbr;
}

int main()
{
    // 1. Map the input file in memory
    const char* inputPath = "C:/Users/1032359/cpp-projects/Straggler Job Analyzer/src/part-00001-of-00500.csv";
    HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFileA(inputPath, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    DWORD highsize;
    DWORD lowsize = GetFileSize(fileHandle, &highsize);
    HANDLE mappingHandle = CreateFileMapping(fileHandle, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, highsize, lowsize, NULL);
    size_t fileSize = (size_t)lowsize | (size_t)highsize << 32;
    const char* memoryAddr = (const char*)MapViewOfFile(mappingHandle, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, fileSize);

    // 2. Find the offset of the start of lines
    std::vector<size_t> linesOffset;
    linesOffset.push_back(0);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < fileSize; i++)
        if (memoryAddr[i] == '\n')
            linesOffset.push_back(i + 1);
    linesOffset.pop_back();

    // 3. sort the offset according to some logic
    std::sort(linesOffset.begin(), linesOffset.end(), [memoryAddr](const size_t& offset1, const size_t& offset2) {
        std::array<uint64_t, 5> nbr1 = readFirst5Numbers(memoryAddr + offset1);
        std::array<uint64_t, 5> nbr2 = readFirst5Numbers(memoryAddr + offset2);
        if (nbr1[4] != nbr2[4])
            return nbr1[4] < nbr2[4];
        if (nbr1[2] != nbr2[2])
            return nbr1[2] < nbr2[2];
        return nbr1[4] < nbr2[4];
        });

    // 4. output sorted array
    const char* outputPath = "C:/Users/1032359/cpp-projects/Straggler Job Analyzer/output/part-00001-of-00500.csv";
    std::ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open(outputPath);
    for (size_t offset : linesOffset)
    {
        const char* line = memoryAddr + offset;
        size_t len = strchr(line, '\n') + 1 - line;
        outputFile.write(line, len);
    }
}
```

Comment: This can be very useful. If the file is to be read many times, one could do the _parsing_ once and just write it down in binary form. All the following times the file needs to be read, just memory-map the whole binary file and work on it directly.

Comment: I've timed your code on my data sample: read/sort took 175 seconds, write - 17. Note the the fie size got increased, I suspect extra CR on each line. I think your code is parsing key fields for EACH compare during sort, which is very inefficient.

Comment: @VladFeinstein Yes, I am aware that this approach is very inefficient, as it parses roughly 24 times each row as already explained. But Ted's comment gives a solution to use both little RAM *and* little CPU.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a slightly different approach:

1. Do NOT parse the entire row, only extract fields that are used for sorting
2. Note that your stated ranges require small number of bits, that together fit in one 64-bit value:

> 30,000,000 - 25 bit
>
> 10,000 - 14 bit
>
> 1,000,000 - 20 bit

3. Save a "raw" source in your vector, so that you can write it out as needed.

Here is what I got:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>

struct Record {
    uint64_t key;
    std::string str;
    Record(uint64_t key, std::string&& str)
        : key(key)
        , str(std::move(str))
    {}
};

int main()
{
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::ifstream src("data.csv");
    std::vector<Record> v;
    std::string str;
    uint64_t key(0);
    while (src >> str)
    {
        size_t pos = str.find(',') + 1;
        pos = str.find(',', pos) + 1;
        char* p(nullptr);
        uint64_t f3 = strtoull(&str[pos], &p, 10);
        uint64_t f4 = strtoull(++p, &p, 10);
        uint64_t f5 = strtoull(++p, &p, 10);
        key  = f5 << 34;
        key |= f3 << 14;
        key |= f4;
        v.emplace_back(key, std::move(str));
    }
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const Record& a, const Record& b) {
        return a.key < b.key;
        });
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << std::endl;

    std::ofstream out("out.csv");
    for (const auto& r : v) {
        out.write(r.str.c_str(), r.str.length());
        out.write("\n", 1);
    }
    auto t3 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t3 - t2).count() << std::endl;
}
```

Of course, you can `reserve` space in your vector upfront to avoid reallocation.

I've generated a file with 18,000,000 records. My timing shows ~30 second for reading / sorting the file, and ~200 seconds to write the output.

**UPDATE:**

Replaced streaming with `out.write()`, reduced writing time from 200 seconds to 17!

Comment: I just compared this with my version on my machine (excluding the saving of the file afterwards). Yours take ~15 seconds and mine ~2 minutes, so if the other fields aren't needed for further processing, just keeping the string _as-is_ is clearly very effective. It'll be very fast at sorting those `Record`s. It may even be worth doing the sorting like you propose and splitting it up into proper fields after the sorting has been done.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I should have mentioned: the reading part only took 28 seconds, and the parsing/sorting added another 3. File I/O is a bottleneck here, demonstrated by the long write time. Simply dropping the SIX trailing zeroes from the first two fields (using milliseconds instead of nanoseconds) will reduce the file size by almost 10%!